# How to determine performance of the query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Here is the query :

```
drop table product

create table product
(
     pid int,
     pnm varchar(10),
     cdt date
)

insert into product 
values(1, 'a', '2015-01-30'), (2, 'a', '2015-03-30'), 
      (3, 'b', '2015-03-30')

delete p 
from 
    (select 
         pid, pnm, cdt,
         rn = row_number() over (partition by pnm order by cdt desc) 
     from product) p
where p.rn > 1

select * from product

;with cte as
(
    select 
        pnm, max(cdt) as x 
    from product
    group by pnm
)
delete p 
from cte a 
join product p on a.pnm = p.pnm and a.x > p.cdt

select * from product
```

Here is the query execution plan for both the queries,the problem is I am not able to determine which query is faster.

[image]

[image]

so,how would I determine which is faster among these and optimize them.

Comment: "I you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses." http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can set IO and Time statistics on using these commands:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
```

By doing that, you will see how much each query took to execute and how many reads/writes were done.

If that doesn't help you, you can download [SQL Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) (there's a free version and compare executions plans.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL Query profile

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/